How to solve a two-dimensional second order neutral delay difference system?
I am trying to solve a system of 2 dimensional (second order) delay difference equations. While searching for the solution, I got the command NDSolve.
I am still confused with my system. Any help will be highly appreciated.
My System:

My attempt:
xm[a_, m_] := a^m
ym[b_, n_] := b^n
NDSolve[xm[a, m + 2] - 2 xm[a, m + 1] + xm[a, m] + 4 (xm[a, m - 3 + 2] - 2 xm[a, m - 3 + 1] + xm[a, m - 3]) + 15 xm[a, m - 2] - (3/2) ym[b, n - 4] == 0 && ym[b, n + 2] - 2 ym[b, n + 1] + ym[b, n] +    4 (ym[b, n - 3 + 2] - 2 ym[b, n - 3 + 1] + ym[b, n - 3]) 33 xm[a, m - 2] - (-9/2) ym[b, n - 4] == 0, {{xm[a, m], 0, 1}, {ym[b, n], 0, 1}}]

For a system of difference equations use  RSolve. If you need to test a trial solution use FullSimplify.

@AlexTrounev Thanks. May I please know how to solve this particular problem?

How would you like to solve this system - in general or with initial conditions?

How to solve this in general?
